# Dynamically changing http.nonProxyHosts at runtime does not work

Tags: java, proxy

I am changing http.nonproxyhosts of JVM.

1. System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts","localhost|127.0.0.1"); Then
   I try to connection to www.google.com then traffic will go through
   Proxy.
2. Now I add a host to list without restarting JVM :
   System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts","localhost|127.0.0.1|www.google.com");
   Traffic still goes through Proxy for www.google.com.

Does dynamic setting for http.nonProxyHosts take effect immediately
without JVM restart? or Does it require JVM restart?

Thanks,
Bhavesh

Comment: Properties are case-sensitive. Correct name is `http.nonProxyHosts`

Comment: @apangin I corrected post.